# using a converter from another silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have silverlight solution that contains three projects

Customs,

Customs.Admin,

Customs.Web

The **Customs** project has got converter class [ConvertoBool] which is used throught the project for its UI. It is used through a ResourceDictionary tag in a ResourceDictionary.xaml file from the **Customs** project.

Now **Customs** being the main project has got a reference to the **Customs.Admin** project where all the UI for admin screens are present.

If I want to reuse the converter class [ConvertoBool] from the **Customs** project in my **Customs.Admin** project, what would be the way to do it?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the following in the app.xaml of **Customs** project

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources/Converters.xaml" /> ...
```

In the Converters.xaml file under folder MyResources of the **Customs** project I created a resource dictionary pointing to the converter class.

That did it!

Answer (score 0):

Converters are just normal classes, so you have to reference the project that contains it. If you cannot reference it because of a circular reference then you'll have to move the Converter and/ore re-think your solution's architecture.